# How to take parameters from the command line inside the main function in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

I'm new to Haxe. My school tasked me to write a Jack compiler in Haxe, so I started learning the language. I can't find anywhere how to take parameters inside the main function. That is, I'd like to call my executable like this :

```
./Main.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

...and read these args inside the main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://api.haxe.org/Sys.html#args.
This method returns your passed arguments as `Array<String>`.

```
static function main() {
    var args = Sys.args();
    var arg1 = args[0];
    var args = args[1];
    //...
}
```